# CV template in overleaf

Tags: cv

In this resume template: How can I move the output of the command `\cvdetail` to the left most side? Nothing seems to work for me.

Link: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/resume/rysrqppxyvdg

Comment: We prefer to have questions self-contained to this site, not at other links where we can't control what happens.  It would be better to post a minimal working example here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just guessing, what "move to left" might or might not mean, I suspect you want to rewrite the `\newcommand`:

- now it's a table
- where the first entry is empty
- AND its width is set to 2.5cm via `p{2.5cm}`

```
\newcommand{\cvdetail}[1]{
  \begin{tabular*}{1\textwidth}{p{2.5cm} p{14.5cm}}
    & \larrow{bgcol}  #1\\ [3pt]
  \end{tabular*}
}
```

So adjust the width to less than 2.5 cm, OR remove the table at all:

```
\newcommand{\cvdetail}[1]{
%  \begin{tabular*}{1\textwidth}{p{2.5cm} p{14.5cm}}
%    & 
\larrow{bgcol}  #1\\ [3pt]
%  \end{tabular*}
}
```